# SVN exporting a list of file names for a given changeset

Tags: svn

I am trying to find a way to export a list of file names in a given changeset. I can access the info in TortoiseSVN very easily using the Log Messages. But I need to record which files have changed in a separate CM tool (not by choice).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use

```
svn diff --revision 1:2 --summarize
```

Which produces a flat list of files added/modified/deleted

Comment: Ooooh... thanks for that. i had no idea as i rarely use the diff commands directly.. it does take a bit longer than `log` but you dont have to scan for the "Changed Paths" if youre scripting since its a flat list.

Comment: This is ever better for my needs. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

`svn log -v -r THE_REV_NUMBER` will get you the log comment plus all the changed paths in the revision.

Answer (score 2):

```
svnlook changed <repository-path> -r <revision>
```

Comment: even better... but doesnt svnlook only work on the system where the repository is housed physically?

Comment: @prodigitalson: I think so, as it takes a repository path instead of URL. So svnlook might not be an option in some cases. As I do have physical access to the machine the repository is located on, svnlook is what I use in my scripts, so that's what immediately came to my mind :)